# Code for countdown timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am creating a countdown timer in Xcode. The user sets the hours, minutes, and seconds, and the app counts down from then. However, I am having some troubles with my code and I can't figure out what to do. This is the code:

```
elapsedTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self->startTime];

int elapsed = (int)elapsedTime - (int)totalStoppedTime;

secondInt = setSecond - (elapsed % 60);
if (secondInt < 0) {
    secondInt = 0;
}
minuteInt = setMinute - ((elapsed / 60) % 60);
if (minuteInt < 0) {
    minuteInt = 0;
    }
hourInt = setHour - (elapsed / 3600);
if (hourInt < 0) {
    hourInt = 0;
}
```

Basically, I create an NSDate when the user starts the timer, and this method is called every 0.5 seconds. It calculates the time that has passed since the start time (taking away the total stopped time - time spent while the user stops the timer), and takes that away from the timer. The first two lines work fine. The trouble I'm having is taking away the elapsed time.

SetSecond/SetMinute/SetHour are the variables that hold the initial seconds, minutes, hours that the user set for the app to countdown from. SecondInt/MinuteInt/HourInt are the variables that hold the time just before it is displayed.

The problem occurs when you set minutes and hours above 0. They do not update until 60 seconds has passed since the start time. Therefore, if you set the minutes at 5, and the seconds at 20, the minutes would not change after 20 seconds, but after 60 seconds instead.

I have tried to explain this the best I can, but if you need more info, please ask.

Thanks for helping!

EDIT: This is my code now:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSUInteger flags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:self->startTime toDate:now options:0];

secondInt = [components second];
minuteInt = [components minute];
hourInt = [components hour];

NSTimeInterval totalElapsed = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self->startTime];
NSTimeInterval netElapsed = totalElapsed - totalStoppedTime;

NSDate *sinceStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:netElapsed sinceDate:self->startTime];
```

I'm getting a warning saying 'Unused variable: sinceStart'. I seriously have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. I'm not very experienced at Objective-C, and i don't know how this is supposed to work.

Please help.

Comment: It's simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

That's non-objective-c notation for "self->startTime", but assuming the rest of the code works, here's a suggestion:

```
// start the timer, self.startDate = [NSDate date];
```

Then in your timer fired method...

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; 
NSTimeInterval totalElapsed = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate];
NSTimeInterval netElapsed = totalElapsed - totalStoppedTime;

NSDate *sinceStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:netElapsed sinceDate:self.startDate];

// now use "sinceStart" in the NSCalendar components call, like this...
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:sinceStart toDate:now options:0];

NSInteger secondInt = [components second];
NSInteger minuteInt = [components minute];
NSInteger hourInt = [components hour];

// use these values in your UI
NSLog(@"there are %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds remaining", [components hour], [components minute], [components second]);
```

Comment: I just edited.  Do you mean where we pull hours, minutes seconds out of the components?  That looked like the goal of your code: to get scalar values for that stuff.  The point is that the calendar can do all the time interval math for you (and do it correctly).

Comment: So if I replace my code with yours, it should be able to count down from the users set time, without the glitch of my code?

Comment: I hope so.  It wasn't super clear what's going wrong with your code, but replace it with mine and NSLog secondInt, minuteInt, etc and you should see those changing how you expect.

Comment: I'll try to explain better; For example, I set the timer at 1 minute, 20 seconds. After that 20 seconds is up, the minutes should decrement to 0, and seconds should go up to 59. However, with my code, when the 20 seconds is up, the minutes stay at 1 because my code only updates minutes when a whole 60 seconds has passed, and the seconds stay at 0. Once a whole 60 seconds has passed, the minutes go down to 0, and the seconds go to 20. I hope this explains it better.

Comment: Yes, I think my suggestion will solve this.  Please give it a try.

Comment: Do I need to copy all of it, or just a part?

Comment: all of it.  replace your code where you compute the secondInt, minuteInt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try code below:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = setSecond + setMinute * 60 + setMinute * 3600;
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:duration sinceDate:self->startDate];
NSTimeInterval remainingTime = [endDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
if(remainingTime <= 0)
    NSLog(@"Finish");

int remainingInSeconds = (int) remainingTime;

secondInt = remainingInSeconds % 60;
remainingInSeconds /= 60;

minuteInt = remainingInSeconds % 60;
remainingInSeconds /= 60;

hourInt = remainingInSeconds % 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the result from your calculation in the NSCalander call.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval totalElapsed = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
NSTimeInterval netElapsed = totalElapsed - totalStoppedTime;

NSDate *sinceStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:netElapsed sinceDate:startTime];

NSUInteger flags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:sinceStart toDate:now options:0];

secondInt = [components second];
minuteInt = [components minute];
hourInt = [components hour];
```